# Angular.js Directive - attempt to modify scope but I get Unexpected identifier

Tags: angularjs

In Angular.js, I am trying to update a $scope value that is in my controller with a directive. I chose "=" since it is 2 way binding...the directive is updating the scope variable.

But I get `Unexpected identifier` with countfrom = "7777". I am trying to update `$scope.countDownTicker` that exists in the controller. I also want the 777 value to show up in the html. I did not return a template since the html code is already there.

```
angular.module('monitorApp', [])
.directive("countDown", function () {
    return {
        scope: {
            countfrom: "="
        }
        countfrom = "7777"
    }
});


<span class="info-test" count-down countfrom="{{countDwnTicker}}"></span>
```

Comment: Need to look at [Directive API](https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.20/docs/api/ng/service/$compile) about structuring them. That scope value can be updated without using any directive. In your particular case what is your end objective?

Comment: This is just learning/experimenting...in this case updating a existing scope value from the directive(I want to use a directive).

Comment: In that case, see my answer below as an initial step to using directives. But do go through docs mentioned above. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modifications required as shown in this demo [PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/yT9LH5CdYrHiZE5kr98v?p=preview). Mainly:

```
app.directive("countDown", function () {
    return {
        scope: {
            countFrom: "="
        },
        link: function(scope){
          scope.countFrom = 777;
        }
    }
});
```

and

```
<span count-down count-from="countDownTicker">{{ countDownTicker }}</span>
```

Highly recommend reading through the link provided in my comment to question.

Comment: I was under the impression I did not have to explicit return a link function when using `scope: { countFrom: "=" } `

Comment: Yes `link` function is the link between the DOM and directive. If the scope were not isolated then only this line in the directive should have been sufficient: `return function(scope){ scope.countDownTicker = 777; }`